# How to Put two DataValueFields?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I bind a product name, then get a product id and price in the label result? The three attributes are from the same table in DB.

**Code:**

```
public partial class CreateOrder : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false) bindListBox();
    }
}

private void bindListBox()
{
    ddlProduct.DataSource     = getReader();
    ddlProduct.DataTextField  = "productName";
    ddlProduct.DataValueField = "IDANDPRICE"; 

    ddlProduct.DataBind();
}

private SqlDataReader getReader()
{
    //get connection string from web.config
    string strConnectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "SELECT productName, productID,productPrice,(productID + '-' +  productPrice) AS IDANDPRICE from Product";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    myConnect.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return reader;
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "";
    Label1.Text += "productName:" + ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text + "<br/>";

    Label2.Text = "";
    Label2.Text += "IDANDPRICE:" + ddlProduct.SelectedItem.ToString() ;

}
```

Comment: A reader is an enumerable object.  You have to use the Read() method to get each row of the enumerable object.  It is better in your case to use a SqlDataAdapter and put results into a DataTable.  Then bind your controls to the DataTable.

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and use an ORM (like Entity Framework) to get *objects* from the database. This makes your life much easier. You can just bind a collection of `Product` objects to the DDL and use SelectedItem.

Answer (score 0):

```
I find the following errors:  

1- cast number filed to nvarchar in sql query
2- set AutoPostBack property of listbox to true
3- use ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value for label2
```

I create a page and use your code and apply above suggestion, the following code work perfectly.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false) bindListBox();
}

private void bindListBox()
{
    ddlProduct.DataSource = getReader();
    ddlProduct.DataTextField = "name";
    ddlProduct.DataValueField = "IdAndName";

    ddlProduct.DataBind();
}

private SqlDataReader getReader()
{
    //get connection string from web.config
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "SELECT Id,Name,CAST( id as nvarchar(10) )+'-'+Name as IdAndName  FROM  Product";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    myConnect.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return reader;
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "";
    Label1.Text += "productName:" + ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text + "<br/>";

    Label2.Text = "";
    Label2.Text += "IDANDPRICE:" + ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value;
}

}
```